# Get WPF context menu to open over win32 child window?

Tags: wpf, interop, contextmenu

I have a child window (or control if you will) that utilizes Direct2D that was programmed in native win32.  I am embedding that window in a WPF ui.  All is good there, using the MSDN  [Hosting a Win32 Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752055.aspx) - with a few tweaks of course.

My WPF app has a context menu that should appear everywhere in the app, but of course it does not work over the win32 child window, as the messages are being sent to its WndProc and not being handled by WPF.

I tried overriding [HwndHost::WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.wndproc.aspx) and did successfully trap the right click, but can't open the "Window.ContextMenu" as at this point I have no access to the MainWindow object.

I even tried crazy stuff like generating a new windows message by importing win32 methods and trying to "trick" WPF to give me a context menu over the win32 child window:

```
if (msg == WM_RBUTTONUP)
{
    IntPtr parent = GetParent(hwndHandle);
    PostMessage(parent, (int)0x0205, (IntPtr)0x0002, lParam);

     handled = true;
}
```

Any push in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try positioning a transparent Wpf window on top of your win32 window, which will allow you to control all mouse events in your wpf, display menus etc. At the same time, you can pass any mouse events you want your Win32 code to see by spoofing WM_LBUTTONDOWN messages etc into the win32.